# How to serve assets files (js, css, images) on a subdomain

Tags: subdomains

Currently I'm setting up a blog on site.com/wordpress and I would like to serve all of my assets for the blog on my asset server, assets.site.com/blog/.

I got the desired results on the front end by changing the siteurl option in the database (wp_options) however the admin routes to that address (the asset server) instead of site.com (which is the value of the home option).

What do I need to change to server assets files from a subdomain (js, css & images)?

Comment: Have you already searched for available filters?

Comment: Hi Kaiser - I have not searched for available filters...will research that. Maybe there is a plugin for doing this?

Comment: Plugin/Theme recommendations are [off topic](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1217/update-our-faq-and-abandon-theme-plugin-recommendations). Maybe you can update your question with a look at the answer from jdm2112 and tell _which_ kind of assets you are trying to offload to a central network site. Narrowing it down might bring more answers.

Comment: Understand about the plugins recommendations but I was specific about which assets to serve from the subdomain (js, css & images).

Comment: But what _is_ "images"? That is what I asked to specify...

Comment: All images would be theme related images, admin images for the admin dash & blog content images. I will prob. sym link the upload directory to be on our asset server so that any user uploads go there.

Comment: So we just found out that there are around a dozen questions for images: How to set a central upload location for all images from all blogs on a multisite/network install? How to replace parent and child theme images that get served with `get_template/stylesheet_directory_uri()`? How to replace the location of all JavaScript and Stylesheets that get loaded with `wp_enqueue_*()`? And so on. Please narrow your question down to a single one: One question per question. Else this is not answerable.

Answer (score 2):

The path to your assets will vary based on where you are calling for those assets.  For example, when referencing a background img URL in a CSS file, this path is relative to the location of the CSS file.  Contrast this with asset calls inside page content - which are relative to the published page location... or an asset call inside a template, etc.

The location from which you request the asset will vary.

You may be forced to use a full absolute URL to the assets.  As long as you know that path, simply use the full http://assets.site.com/folder/file.ext

Comment: Thanks jdm for your answer. I understand about the relative versus full path.  I think what I was looking for is some kind of 3rd option for wordpress where there is a "home", "siteurl" and some kind of "asseturl".

Comment: Do you know where I can add the full url path for all stylesheets and js assets?  Somewhere in the wp_head() function like get_stylesheet_directory_uri()?

Comment: Ideally you would use the WP functions for these references such as: `<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>`.  With your assets located elsewhere, that method would not work.  You could try declaring a variable in your functions.php file like this: `$assets_loc = "http://assets.domain.td/path";`.  Then use it in your templates like this: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php echo $assets_loc; ?>/style.css"  />`